# How to print the relationships in a family tree when one parent has multiple no of children using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, binary-tree, nodes

[image]

Above is the family tree, from which I have to print the relationship from the input is given any name.
How to approach with this one since it has multiple branches, unlike binary tree which has only 2 twigs left and write.

Comment: What technique would you do on a binary tree to solve this problem that wouldn't work on any [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)? Either a breadth-first search or a depth first search would work just fine on a tree like this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but you can traverse this tree just like a normal binary tree. you just store every node children in an array (instead of left, right properties). You can then either choose BFS or DFS. here's kind of a pseudocode for DFS.

```
const traverse = (root) => {
  root.children.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(child.value)
    traverse(child)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't possibly give a code answer without knowing what format this data is in, but as a general approach:

1. Organize your data and define a function on it that gets the "neighbors" of any given node (i.e. parents, children, siblings, and spouses)
2. Perform a [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) of your graph starting at the given person and using the above function until you find the second person you are looking for. Keep track of the path you take. (e.g. `Start -> Parent -> Sibling -> Child`)
3. Make some function or lookup table to convert these paths to named relationships. E.g. `(Start -> Parent -> Sibling -> Child) :: Cousin`. Probably, this would need to be a hard-coded list of common relationships (like brother, sister, grandfather, uncle, etc.) along with some logic to output `nth-great` or `n-times-removed` versions of those relationships for arbitrarily large `n`.